# Server suddenly has high softirq cpu use after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, cpu-usage, interrupts

A 48 GB RAM virtual server maintaining about 25k TCP connections (devices in the field logging in to set up an SSH tunnel) ran out of RAM and started swapping, and getting slow, etc. We upgraded and rebooted. Even after the 25k connections had been restored and the initial DDOS storm dealt with, the server now showed an enormous amount of softirq use. How do I find the cause?

Here you can see the events:

[image: Munin CPU graph]

It's striking that there didn't used to be a lot of softirq. Now, there are 8 kernel threads doing about 60% CPU of it (`ksoftirqd` threads).

Looking at Munin graphs, I see the interrupts of `PCI-MSI 49153-edge virtio0-input.0` has increased a lot (mind the log y scale):

[image: Munin interrupts graphs]

The amount of network traffic the machine has to deal with didn't really change.

I wrote a quick python script that shows the interrupts per second, every second, from `/proc/interrupts` from `PCI-MSI 49153-edge virtio0-input.0`, and it mostly is about 50-100 per second, but every once in a while, there is a 5000 - 10000 burst.

Because in the upgrade process, the VM hoster's control panel announced that it needed to migrate the VM to another server. I theorized that that server has a different Ethernet controller, differently emulated interrupt controller, or whatever, but they even migrated the VM back, and there's no difference.

Another difference is that the VM went from `vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic` to `/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic`. With all the Intel CPU patches lately, I can imagine something snuck in there.

The big question is, how do I get to the root cause, or get more info where these interrupts come from? Rebooting the server to the old kernel is possible, but not desirable.

Comment: Let me add some specificity about the upgrade: ① the server went from 48 GB RAM to 64 GB; ② The server went from 6 CPU cores to 8. My (unfounded) gut feeling is that upping these specs even further _could_ help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out somebody installed atop, which has a systemd service that collections process accounting information. Removing it fixed it.